# CAS Service Ticket for Standalone Application

Tags: java, spring-security, cas

My CAS environment includes the CAS server and 2 (Grails) webapps (API and UI) such that

CAS Server:  (CAS + Spring Security with RESTful API enabled)
    `https://server/cas/login`
Service 1:   (main user UI which communicates with app-api via proxy)
    `https://server/app/j_spring_cas_security_check`
Service 2:
    `https://server/app-api/j_spring_cas_security_check`

The "app" communicates with "app-api" by querying for a Proxy Ticket like so ...

```
String getProxyTicketFor( String serviceUrl ) {
    String ticket = null;
    try {
        def context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        def auth = context?.getAuthentication();
        def assertion = auth?.getAssertion();
        def principal = assertion?.getPrincipal();
        ticket = principal?.getProxyTicketFor( serviceUrl );
    } catch(e) { ... }
    return ticket;
}
```

This was all setup previously before me and works as intended.

Separate from this I also have a "legacy" Java Web Start (Jnlp) app which communicates via a custom port to a back-end server running on JBoss.

My task and problem is the following - I would like to have this JWS server be able to communicate with the casified webapp (service 1) on behalf of the authenticated cas user
via a Service Ticket passed in through the Jnlp launcher. The user is able to launch the JNLP via the "app" UI which then allows interactions between the Java Web Start Client and it's server.  We'd like to have the JWS Server be able to communicate with Service 1 on behalf of the user without having to re-enter credentials.

I've been requesting a service ticket from "app" using it's own Service1 url and getting a proper service ticket such as ST-66-IlSRiXhm54ooRFeUXOZO-cas.

The basic gist of what I'm trying to do seems to work when I test using Curl to first hit the RESTful API to generate a Service Ticket and then using a different Curl session to use the ticket.

```
// 1. Request TGT - Response TGT TICKET: [TGT-18-CZfUKZMjQWfwTE4fkUOqihhoNVRhpLg2KNcxxtYZd2QJHRmdLN-cas]
$ curl -k -s -c cookie1.txt -b cookie1.txt -d username=user1&password=password https://server/cas/v1/tickets

// 2. Request ST using TGT - Response ST TICKET: ST-18-1WqgeEsRBSLQ92GeOwXx-cas
$ curl -k -s -c cookie1.txt -b cookie1.txt -d service=https://server/app/j_spring_cas_security_check https://server/cas/v1/tickets/TGT-18-CZfUKZMjQWfwTE4fkUOqihhoNVRhpLg2KNcxxtYZd2QJHRmdLN-cas

// 3. Use ST Ticket to "validate" connection against the Spring Security service    ticket consumption page
$ curl -k -s -c cookie2.txt -b cookie2.txt -d ticket=ST-18-1WqgeEsRBSLQ92GeOwXx-cas https://server/app/j_spring_cas_security_check -o output1.txt -L

// 4. I am now able to reach my protected document
$ curl -k -s -c cookie2.txt -b cookie2.txt https://server/app/document.txt -o output2.txt -L
```

To test the Service Ticket I requested earlier from "app" to use with my JNLP I've basically been using the ST received to manually do steps 3 and 4 above - it fails at step 3. 
When I try to use it I get an AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS followed quickly by a PROXY_GRANTING_TICKET_NOT_CREATED.

Error Message

```
=============================================================
WHO: [callbackUrl: https://server/app/casCommunicator/proxyCallback]
WHAT: supplied credentials: [callbackUrl: https://server/app/casCommunicator/proxyCallback]
ACTION: AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Wed Sep 19 17:23:37 EDT 2012
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
=============================================================

2012-09-19 17:23:37,058 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry] - Attempting to retrieve ticket [ST-32-ffeocQpdbYwtblIydlOm-cas]
2012-09-19 17:23:37,058 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry] - Ticket [ST-32-ffeocQpdbYwtblIydlOm-cas] found in registry.
2012-09-19 17:23:37,058 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry] - Attempting to retrieve ticket [ST-32-ffeocQpdbYwtblIydlOm-cas]
2012-09-19 17:23:37,058 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry] - Ticket [ST-32-ffeocQpdbYwtblIydlOm-cas] found in registry.
2012-09-19 17:23:37,058 INFO [com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: https://server/app/casCommunicator/proxyCallback
WHAT: org.jasig.cas.ticket.InvalidTicketException
ACTION: PROXY_GRANTING_TICKET_NOT_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Wed Sep 19 17:23:37 EDT 2012
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
=============================================================

2012-09-19 17:23:37,058 ERROR [org.jasig.cas.web.ServiceValidateController] - TicketException generating ticket for: [callbackUrl: https://server/app/casCommunicator/proxyCallback]
org.jasig.cas.ticket.InvalidTicketException
    at org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.delegateTicketGrantingTicket_aroundBody6(CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.java:278)
    at org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.delegateTicketGrantingTicket_aroundBody7$advice(CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.java:44)
    at org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.delegateTicketGrantingTicket(CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.java:1)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor44.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80)
    at org.perf4j.aop.AbstractTimingAspect$1.proceed(AbstractTimingAspect.java:47)
    at org.perf4j.aop.AgnosticTimingAspect.runProfiledMethod(AgnosticTimingAspect.java:53)
    at org.perf4j.aop.AbstractTimingAspect.doPerfLogging(AbstractTimingAspect.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor31.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:161)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80)
    at com.github.inspektr.audit.AuditTrailManagementAspect.handleAuditTrail(AuditTrailManagementAspect.java:126)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor30.invoke(Unknown Source)
)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:161)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy20.delegateTicketGrantingTicket(Unknown Source)
    at org.jasig.cas.web.ServiceValidateController.handleRequestInternal(ServiceValidateController.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeDispatcherServlet.service_aroundBody2(SafeDispatcherServlet.java:115)
    at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeDispatcherServlet.service_aroundBody3$advice(SafeDispatcherServlet.java:44)
    at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeDispatcherServlet.service(SafeDispatcherServlet.java:1)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.github.inspektr.common.web.ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.doFilter(ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
2012-09-19 17:23:37,063 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry] - Attempting to retrieve ticket [ST-32-ffeocQpdbYwtblIydlOm-cas]
2012-09-19 17:23:37,063 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry] - Ticket [ST-32-ffeocQpdbYwtblIydlOm-cas] found in registry.
2012-09-19 17:23:37,064 INFO [org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl] - ServiceTicket [ST-32-ffeocQpdbYwtblIydlOm-cas] has expired.
2012-09-19 17:23:37,064 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry] - Removing ticket [ST-32-ffeocQpdbYwtblIydlOm-cas] from registry
2012-09-19 17:23:37,064 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry] - Attempting to retrieve ticket [ST-32-ffeocQpdbYwtblIydlOm-cas]
2012-09-19 17:23:37,064 INFO [com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: audit:unknown
WHAT: ST-32-ffeocQpdbYwtblIydlOm-cas
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_VALIDATE_FAILED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Wed Sep 19 17:23:37 EDT 2012
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
=============================================================
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible?   If so - do you see anything wrong with my implementations.